Django-MySQL remote connection trouble
I was trying to connect my app with a remote MySQL database (usually obtained from our hosting through cPanel) and encountered this error. Can anyone help me out? I'm stuck here. Does Django really allow remote MySQL connections?
Screenshot of the problem
I tried the official documentation for the Django-MySQL connection, but it didn't work for me. I couldn't find any suitable tutorials on YouTube either.
